# Shrinking and fading annotation to another image

Tags: ios, swift, animation, mapkit, mkannotationview

In my app I would like to have placed annotations start as A larger image and slowly fade to a different image while shrinking down to the proper size.

I have the following code, written in Swift 3:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views {
        if let place = view.annotation as? ImportantPlace {
            let bigImage = UIImage(named: place.id)
            let smallImage = UIImage(named: "image2")

            view.image = bigImage


            UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 2.0,
                              options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .transitionCrossDissolve],
                              animations: {
                                view.image = smallImage

                }, completion: nil )
        } 
    }
}
```

Currently the annotation begins at the correct size however it has the small image from the start and simply shrinks.

Thanks for any help